# Vue router how to trigger navigation guards before entering external domain

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a Vue application and need to know when a user is about to navigate out of my application.

I have a beforeRouteLeave in place that triggers an alert if I go from myvueapp.nl/example to myvueapp.nl/example2 however if I navigate from myvueapp.nl/example to [www.google.nl](http://www.google.nl) it doesn't trigger.

The reason I need to do this is the following:

You can navigate to /example/123 and this will open the example page and open a modal showing the user data of person 123. when you close this modal a router.go(-1) will be triggered. This allows me to use nested modal views. However if you go from google.com directly to /example/123 and then close the modal you will be send back to google.com. My idea was to check where a user is about to navigate to and if it is outside my domain I will check if the modal is open. is the modal open then close that instead of navigation. If it was already closed then let the user go on their way.

How can I know when a user is about to navigate out of my application?

Comment: `beforeRouteLeave` will trigger only when you are navigating in the same domain between different routes. Try using the `window.unload` event

Comment: window.unload wont help my usecase. I added in some more information on why I need to do this.

Comment: Why do you think `window.unload` will not help ? It will detect when the current page is being replaced with another page.